# Cakephp3 Joining models form 2 databases

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I wanted to ask, if it is possible do get data from associated models, which are using 2 databases ?

I have 2 Models:
Docs and Files
They have relation hasOne();

Docs lives in doc and Files is using file database.

Now i try to :

```
$file = TableRegistry::get('Docs');
$query = $res->find('all')->contain('Files')->where(['status'=>100])->limit('3')->toArray();
```

Result is:
    Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'doc.files' doesn't exist

But, Files model looks like this:

```
public static function defaultConnectionName() {
    return 'file';
}
```

So, question is - how can i get data from database using 2 joined models, which are using 2 databases ?

Thank You.

Comment: You can't tag cake2 and cake3. Which version are you actually using?

Comment: I'm using Cakephp3, but i think, that logic may be common for versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't associate two models that belong to different datasources/databases. When you use a `belongsTo` or `hasOne` relationship Cake will try and use a `JOIN` statement when it creates the SQL; as a result both tables need to exist in the same database.

You will need to query the two datasources/databases separately and combine your results afterwards. I'd recommend checking out [Cake's Hash utility](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html) for simplifying array manipulation for this.

Comment: If i could pass array of ID's as conditions of other find, it would be great.